# Load Scene in AssetBundle and Unload

Tags: unity-game-engine

I load a scene in my AssetBundle like this:

```
IEnumerator AsyncLoad ()
{
    using (var www = new WWW("file://" + Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/scenes"))
    {
        yield return www;

        var bundle = www.assetBundle;

        Application.LoadLevel("Scene1");

        bundle.Unload(false);
    }
}
```

The problem is sometimes `Application.LoadLevel("Scene1");` works fine and sometimes Scene1 is empty. What's wrong here?

Side note: I noticed LoadLevel destroys the current scene before loading, so the lines after LoadLevel are not being executed (since the script was destroyed). As I need to unload the asset bundle in order to use it again another time, what's the solution?

**Unity 5**

Answer (score 0):

you want to use dontdestroyonload on the object that has this loading script attached
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Answer (score 0):

Application.LoadLevel will postpone load sceneobjects next frame, so you need to postpone unload AssetBundles.

```
IEnumerator AsyncLoad (){
using (var www = new WWW("file://" + Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/scenes")){
        yield return www;
        var bundle = www.assetBundle;
        Application.LoadLevel("Scene1");
        yield return null; // THIS LINE IS ADDED
        bundle.Unload(false);
    }
}
```

This may work for you.